# Read .pptx file from s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, python-pptx

I try to open a .pptx from Amazon S3 and read it using the python-pptx library. This is the code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj=s3.Object('bucket','key')
body = obj.get()['Body']
prs=Presentation((body))
```

It gives "AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'seek'". Shouldn't this work? How can I fix this? I also tried using read() on body first.
Is there a solution without actually downloading the file?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Also, it is impossible to display the file without downloading it - either to disk or memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To load files from S3 you should download (or use stream strategy) and use `io.BytesIO` to transform your data as `pptx.Presentation` can handle.

```
import io
import boto3

from pptx import Presentation

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_response_object = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='file.pptx')
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()

prs = Presentation(io.BytesIO(object_content))
```

ref:

`Just like what we do with variables, data can be kept as bytes in an in-memory buffer when we use the io module’s Byte IO operations.` [journaldev](https://www.journaldev.com/19178/python-io-bytesio-stringio)

Comment: How would you then save/write the file back to s3?

Comment: @blue_chip https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.185/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Comment: But from what I understand, `prs` is not a file or file-like object so I don't see how I can use it with `upload_file()`. It's this conversion from Presentation object to file-like object that I'm lost with. Btw, thanks for replying!

Comment: @blue_chip You can make the reverse steps. Use the BytesIO to create a buffer and use that to send to S3. Take a look at ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525338/how-to-upload-stream-to-aws-s3-with-python