# How to upload a .pptx using pptx, io and boto3 in python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, io, boto3, python-pptx

I used the reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890375/read-pptx-file-from-s3) in order to read a .pptx (a template) from s3 using boto3 and io. I updated the .pptx and I now want to upload it back to s3 with a new name.

I see that boto3 has a [method to upload a file-like object to s3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.185/guide/s3-uploading-files.html): `upload_fileobj()`.

So this is what I'm doing when trying to save the file:

```
import io
import boto3

from pptx import Presentation

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_response_object = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='file.pptx')
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()

prs = Presentation(io.BytesIO(object_content))

# Do some stuff to the PowerPoint

out = io.BytesIO() # to have the presentation in binary format
with open(prs.save(out), "rb") as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, 'BUCKET', 'KEY')
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1956d13a7556> in <module>
----> 1 with open(prs.save(out), "rb") as f:
      2     s3.upload_fileobj(f, 'BUCKET', 'KEY')

TypeError: expected

 str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

How can I upload it to s3 given that I start from a Presentation object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import io
import boto3

from pptx import Presentation

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_response_object = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket', Key='file.pptx')
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()

prs = Presentation(io.BytesIO(object_content))

# Do some stuff to the PowerPoint

with io.BytesIO() as out:
    prs.save(out)
    out.seek(0)
    s3.upload_fileobj(out, 'BUCKET', 'KEY')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked (both before and after your first edit)! Seems so simple now that you gave me the correct way to do it.

Comment: Np :) The latter one works better since the `with` block automatically closes the IO stream on exit.